# How to launch SMS Message app

Tags: ios, swift

I want to open SMS Message App to copy some text from friends. I am not creating SMS.

How to launch iphone SMS Message app using Swift code?
I come across this code below for launching Mail app but not working.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:"]];
```

I changed it to and the same not working

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:"]];
```

appreciate your help. TIA

Comment: If you are working on simulator it will not work. Try on real device.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
// Swift 3
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "sms:")!)

// Swift 4
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "sms:")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: I wonder why it did not work? I copied your code inside an IBAction for button to click to launch the SMS app.

Comment: did you use real device? and could you post some code?because it works for me.

Comment: You are right. I am testing it on Simulator. Will your code work in real device that it will open up the SMS message app which will show all the incoming SMS(es). I can click on it and make copy say, GPS latlon send by friends. the format is "sms:"( No space)  and not "sms: " ( with a space after : ?)

Comment: 1.it won't, you need to cancel to back the view.2.the format is "sms:"( No space)

Comment: This is what I wanted: have a btn inside mainVC, click it to launch SMS App ( just like open SMS app in the HomeScreen) , when finish copying some text in selected SMS, close it to return to MainVC.  Is your code above allow me to do this? I will have my real device soon. Sorry to ask this again.

Answer (score 26):

Swift 5:

```
let sms = "sms:+1234567890&body=Hello Abc How are You I am ios developer."
let strURL = sms.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: strURL)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: As an addition to this, to send it to multiple numbers use this:
sms = "sms:open?addresses=802-555-2341,702-555-4328,914-555-1234&body=time to play"

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you want to explicitly use SMS app and I'm not sure if it's possible. On the other hand iOS by default offers `MFMessageComposeViewController` for sending SMS from iOS app.

Check this Swift [example](http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/28/send-text-message-in-app-using-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-with-swift/) for more details.

**Edit:**
I've found this [wiki page](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#SMS) which may contain answer for your question. Be aware I haven't tested it.

```
let number = "sms:+12345678901"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: number)!)
```

Comment: I just want to open the SMS App to copy some text from friends. Ie GPS LatLon. Can you convert your code in swift?

Comment: Your code is to open a specific Mobile Phone No. But I just want to open the SMS message app which will show all the incoming sms. any idea to do it?

Comment: You can try sending empty number, i.e. "sms:" but it will not open up app incoming SMS messages. I'm not sure if that is possible in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about how to launch the SMS Message App. But in case if someone wants to open the SMS composer without leaving the current app, here's a way to achive this.

Let's say the below function is triggered when the user taps on the *send sms* button

```
private func sendSMSButtonAction() {
    guard MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() else {
        print("Unable to send messages.")
        return
    }

    let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    // controller.messageComposeDelegate = self // Confirm this if you want to check the result when the user dismisses the controller.
    controller.recipients = ["+12345678901"]
    controller.body = "Some text"
    present(controller, animated: true)
}
```

Please make sure you've imported the MessageUI in your controller.