# Sending SMS from UITableViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sms

I'd like to send SMS from my UITableViewController but the SMS window does't dismiss after sending or cancel.

```
import MessageUI

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let msgVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    msgVC.recipients = ["555555"]

    self.presentViewController(msgVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!,
                                  didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never set the `messageComposeDelegate`.

```
import MessageUI

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let msgVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    msgVC.messageComposeDelegate = self

    msgVC.recipients = ["555555"]

    self.presentViewController(msgVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!,
                                  didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

  }

}
```

You should also confirm that the device is setup to send messages. Please read the documentation for the `MFMessageComposeViewController` class. It explains all of this and shows sample code as well.

Comment: I followed [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/) documentation, but I seemed to mistype something. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to invoke the built in sms (Swift 3) on didSelect:
UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string:"sms: number w/o spaces") as! URL)

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31180495/how-to-launch-sms-message-app) swift 2 solution or [this](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-send-sms-text-message/) objective-c solution (see latter part).